# qsorting a struct with arrays, error as output

Tags: c, arrays, structure, qsort

1. The output of the program should be like this, but with each item sorted by "nummer"

> nummer: 30871
>   namn: Eternal Darkness
>   pris: 39.799999
>   volym: 330.000000
>   typ: Porter och stout
>   stil: Imperial porter och stout
>   forpackning: Flaska
>   land: Sverige
>   producent: Beerbliotek AB
>   alkoholhalt: 11.000000(this is one item, with 10 elements)

2. The output im getting now is a bit messy and wrong

   > nummer: 1966644114
   >   namn: £
   >   pris: 0.000000
   >   volym: 0.000000
   >   typ:
   >   stil:
   >   forpackning:
   >   land:
   >   producent:
   >   alkoholhalt: 0.000000
3. My guess is that `NUM_ITEMS` is wrong
4. An example from row from "varor.csv" each element is devided by a comma:

30854,Stigbergets West Coast India Pale Ale,32.90,330.00,Ale brittisk-amerikansk stil,India pale ale (IPA),Flaska, Sverige,Stigbergets Bryggeri,6.50

```
#define max(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
#define min(a,b) ((b)>(a)?(a):(b))
#define NUM_ITEMS (sizeof(items) / sizeof(items[0])) 

char *oneline, *tok;
    char envara[512];
    char delim[] = ",";
    FILE *fp;
    int i;

struct vara
{
    int nummer;
    char namn[100];
    float pris;
    float volym;
    char typ[100];
    char stil[100];
    char forpackning[20];
    char land[20];
    char producent[50];
    float alkoholhalt;
} items[100];


    if ((fp = fopen("varor.csv", "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Filen varor.csv gick inte att öppna\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 100 && fgets(envara, 512, fp); i++) {
        envara[strcspn(envara, "\n")] = '\0';
        oneline = strdup(envara);
```

...

```
        tok = strtok(oneline, delim);
        items[i].nummer = atoi(tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        strncpy(items[i].namn, tok, sizeof items[i].namn); items[i].namn[(sizeof items[i].namn) - 1] = 0;
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        items[i].pris = atof(tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        items[i].volym = atof(tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        strncpy(items[i].typ, tok, sizeof items[i].typ); items[i].typ[(sizeof items[i].typ) - 1] = 0;
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        strncpy(items[i].stil, tok, sizeof items[i].stil); items[i].stil[(sizeof items[i].stil) - 1] = 0;
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        strncpy(items[i].forpackning, tok, sizeof items[i].forpackning); items[i].forpackning[(sizeof items[i].forpackning) - 1] = 0;
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        strncpy(items[i].land, tok, sizeof items[i].land); items[i].land[(sizeof items[i].land) - 1] = 0;
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        strncpy(items[i].producent, tok, sizeof items[i].producent); items[i].producent[(sizeof items[i].producent) - 1] = 0;
        tok = strtok(NULL, delim);
        items[i].alkoholhalt = atof(tok);

int nummer_sortering(const void* n1, const void* n2)
{
    const struct vara *item1 = n1;
    const struct vara *item2 = n2;

    return item1->nummer - item2->nummer;
}
```

...

```
printf("\n\nVaror sorterade på varunummer:\n");
qsort(items, i, sizeof(struct vara), nummer_sortering);
for (i = 0; i < NUM_ITEMS; i++)
    {

    printf("nummer: %d\n"
                    "namn: %s\n"
                    "pris: %f\n"
                    "volym: %f\n"
                    "typ: %s\n"
                    "stil: %s\n"
                    "forpackning: %s\n"
                    "land: %s\n"
                    "producent: %s\n"
                    "alkoholhalt: %f\n\n",
                    items[i].nummer,
                    items[i].namn,
                    items[i].pris,
                    items[i].volym,
                    items[i].typ,
                    items[i].stil,
                    items[i].forpackning,
                    items[i].land,
                    items[i].producent,
                    items[i].alkoholhalt
                );


                free(oneline);

        }
    }


    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: It helps if you post all the code and learning how to use a debugger is really helpful when you need to debug a program.

Comment: Could you add declarations of `items`?

Comment: You are getting an error from the linker. My best guess is that there is an instance of the program running and that Windows has locked `systemet.exe` thus preventing you (the linker) from writing to it.

Comment: The second parameter to `qsort` should be the current number of elements. Is the array filled with 100 *varor*?

Comment: This would be why you should always write all your source code in English. At some point you might need other people to read it... for example when asking for help from SO.

Comment: My guess is: `items` can hold up to 100 elements, you have initialized less than 100. The `NUM_ITEMS` macros returns the number of items that `items` can hold, not the number of initialized items. You are sorting over the whole list with initialized and uninitialized items. Perhaps, instead of passing `NUM_ITEMS` to `qsort`, you should pass the number of initialized items. Also all initialized items should come before all uninitialized items.

Comment: I will add all the code! It should be 100 "varor" with 10 elements each.

Comment: the program works just fine without the qsort btw

Comment: `strncpy(items[i].typ, tok, strlen(tok));` I love it!

Comment: This probably seems like a mess to you, I am studying to be an electrical engineer and in one small course we were supposed to do a program, however I "suck" at it as you can see.

Comment: been stuck on this sorting issue for a while now

Comment: `strncpy(items[i].namn, tok, (max(strlen(tok), sizeof(items[0].namn))));` is certainly poor code as the number of characters copied may exceed the array `items[i].namn`.  In general OP's use of `strncpy()` results in non-strings or over-runs.

Comment: For now, change all `strncpy(a,b,n);` to `strncpy(a, b, sizeof a); a[(sizeof a) - 1] = 0;` and see if it helps.

Comment: could you give me some clues on how to proceed

Comment: Post some of varor.csv.

Comment: Definition of `envara` is missing as used in `fgets(envara, 512, fp)`   Post true compilable code.

Comment: added example row from the file! "char envara[512];" it is in the beginning of the question!

Comment: It _might_ not matter here (haven't checked to be sure) but if you're using macros-defined expressions, always wrap them in an outer set of parentheses, as in: `#define max(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))` and `#define NUM_ITEMS (sizeof(items) / sizeof(items[0]))` -- it prevents unexpected problems with operator precedence.

Comment: Thanks TripeHound will remember that

Comment: Regarding the error message you quoted: is the word "error" and parentheses a part of the error message you get, or is this text you added for clarity?

Comment: anatolyg changed it! it was for clarity purpose

Comment: I have edited the code, the error was me being clumsy